# Calculated Column Working Not Working

Tags: javascript, 2016, calculated-column, 2019

I have a calculated column that worked in SharePoint 2007, 2010, 2013, and 2016.  But now in SharePoint 2019 the calculated column is not appearing right in the column instead of showing the employees email address as a hyperlink it now shows the DIV tag info

Is this SharePoint 2019?  Why is this not working?

```
=CONCATENATE("<DIV><a href='","mailto:",[E-Mail],"'>",[Full Name (First M.I. Last)],"</a></DIV>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I think that is the way it is headed. According to [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), the June 2017 update for SP 2013 and 2016 included a switch called **CustomMarkupInCalculatedFieldDisabled**. It allowed your administrator to choose if HTML would show up for calculated fields.

I can't find complete documentation, but searches seem to suggest that the switch is no longer available in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using JSON column formatting is the way to go

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
   "target": "_blank",
   "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
```

}
}